# Iterate XML tags in postgresql

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I want to parse an XML data and store it into table. My XML sample data looks like below

```
<POLICY PolicyNumber="06C1551076" StartDate="20210830" EndDate="20220830" PolicyType="Membersafe" PMSLOBCode="HPP" PMSPolType=" " TxnReference="001" CreationDate="20210715" CreationTime="032937" EffectiveDate="20210830" TxnType="TakeUp" MarketingAuthorisation="N" NetOfCommission="N" CallType="I" IndexedRenewal="Y" RenewalUnderwritingMode="Auto" TerrorismLevyExempt="N" InceptionDate="20120801" PolicyTerm="012" ClaimsReview="N">
    <MEMBERSAFE>
        <HOUSEHOLD RiskID="01" CoverType="ListedEvents" VoluntaryExcess="600" ImposedExcess="0" WallsConstruction="BrickVeneer" Size="0" BuildingType="House" BuildingLevel="Unknown" Occupied="Family" YearOfConstruction="1974" Deadlocks="Y" Alarm="NoAlarm">
            <CONTENTS>
                <SPECIFIEDCONTENTS SumInsured="9264">
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="COMPUTER AND ACCESSORIES" SumInsured="3523"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="18CT Y/G DIAMOND RING" SumInsured="1050"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="9CT Y/G SAPPHIRE AND DIAMOND DRE" SumInsured="850"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="18CT Y/G SAPPHIRE AND DIAMOND EN" SumInsured="810"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="750 Y/G BRACELET" SumInsured="475"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="RUSSIAN WEDDER" SumInsured="420"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="375 Y/G GARNET AND PEARL DRESS R" SumInsured="360"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="375 Y/G SAPPHIRE AND DIAMOND ETE" SumInsured="355"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="585 Y/G GOLD CHAIN" SumInsured="335"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="9CT Y/G GOLD CHAIN" SumInsured="300"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="18CT Y/G LADIES WEDDER" SumInsured="255"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="9CT Y/G SAPPHIRE EARRINGS" SumInsured="180"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="9CT Y/G CUBIC ZIRCONIA EARRING" SumInsured="120"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="9CT Y/G GOLD CHAIN" SumInsured="115"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="375 Y/G HOOP EARRINGS" SumInsured="85"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="TWIST DESIGN EARRINGS" SumInsured="30"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="CAMERA AND ACCESSORIES AS PER AP" SumInsured="1"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                </SPECIFIEDCONTENTS>
            </CONTENTS>
        </HOUSEHOLD>
    </MEMBERSAFE>
</POLICY>
```

I have written a postgresql function using CTE and generate series function to iterate over XML tags. But, this function is taking long to execute if I increase value of generate series to 1000

```
with range_num as
    (
      select generate_series(1, 20) v_loopcounter
    )
    select (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyNumber', payload::xml))[1] policynumber
         , (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyType', payload::xml))[1] PolicyType
         , cntr1.v_loopcounter as HOUSEHOLD_sequence_id
         , cntr2.v_loopcounter as SPECIFIEDITEM_sequence_id
         , (xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD['||cntr1.v_loopcounter||']/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM['||cntr2.v_loopcounter||']/@SumInsured', payload::xml))[1]::text::bigint as SPECIFIEDITEM_SumInsured
         , (xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD['||cntr1.v_loopcounter||']/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM['||cntr2.v_loopcounter||']/@Description', payload::xml))[1]::text::text as SPECIFIEDITEM_Description

    from pms_source_xml_risks  

    cross join range_num cntr1

    cross join range_num cntr2

    where (xpath_exists('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD['||cntr1.v_loopcounter||']/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM['||cntr2.v_loopcounter||']/@SumInsured', payload::xml) = TRUE
    or xpath_exists('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD['||cntr1.v_loopcounter||']/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM['||cntr2.v_loopcounter||']/@Description', payload::xml) = TRUE
)   
and batch_ref_id = 'PMS_20210802_1055-1';
```

Is there an efficient way to extract XML data and get sequence ids based on how many times particular XML tag is repeating?
In example above HOUSEHOLD tag is repeated 1 time and SPECIFIEDITEM for 17 times so value of `HOUSEHOLD_sequence_id` will be 1 and value of `SPECIFIEDITEM_sequence_id` will be from 1 to 17.

I am expecting below result but in efficient way
[image]

If I use unnest I can get all the values but I am not able to set HOUSEHOLD_sequence_id & SPECIFIEDITEM_sequence_id

```
    select (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyNumber', payload::xml))[1]::text policynumber
         , (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyType', payload::xml))[1]::text PolicyType
--         , cntr1.v_loopcounter as HOUSEHOLD_sequence_id
--         , cntr2.v_loopcounter as SPECIFIEDITEM_sequence_id
         , unnest((xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM/@SumInsured', payload::xml))::text[])::bigint as SPECIFIEDITEM_SumInsured
         , unnest((xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM/@Description', payload::xml))::text[])::text as SPECIFIEDITEM_Description
         from pc_extract_uat2.pms_source_xml_risks psxr 
    where batch_ref_id = 'PMS_20210802_1055-1'
    and policy_number = '06C1551076'
    and (xpath_exists('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM/@SumInsured', payload::xml) = TRUE
    or xpath_exists('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM/@Description', payload::xml) = TRUE)   
;
```

I found XML which has two HOUSEHOLD tags and in 2nd tag I have two SPECIFIFEDITEM tags, but output of the query gives something else

```
    <MEMBERSAFE>
        <HOUSEHOLD RiskID="01" CoverType="AccidentalDamage" VoluntaryExcess="600" ImposedExcess="0" WallsConstruction="BrickVeneer" Size="0" BuildingType="House" BuildingLevel="Unknown" Occupied="OwnersBoarders" YearOfConstruction="1992" Deadlocks="Y" Alarm="NoAlarm">
            <RISKADDRESS AddressId="051208029" GeoReliability="2" AddressLine1="1500 ALISON ST" Suburb="MOUNT HELENA" Postcode="006082" State="WA"></RISKADDRESS>
            <POLICYTEXT TextType="AdditionalComments" TextRetention="ThisTermOnly" UseCode="AQ" Text="UPPER LIMIT CAP IMPACT 50.62%                               442"></POLICYTEXT>
            <BUILDING SumInsured="1261400" CoverBasis="Replacement">
                <COVERSTATUS Status="NEW" StartDate="20210729"></COVERSTATUS>
                <PAYABLES>
                    <SPLIT Premium="4244.05"></SPLIT>
                    <RATINGINFORMATION RatingMethod="Auto" AdjustmentPercent="-50.62" CommissionRate1="0.00000" CommissionRate2="0.00000" ExemptStampDuty="Y" PMSLink="1004420010" PriorTermBilledPremium="2803.82" PriorTermAnnualPremium="3858.23" PriorTermSumInsured="1201300" PriorTermExcess="600"></RATINGINFORMATION>
                </PAYABLES>
                <ADJUSTMENT AdjustmentRetention="Permanent" AdjustmentType="Percent" AdjustmentValue="20.00000" AdjustmentReason="OWNER AND TENANT ON SAME TITLE"></ADJUSTMENT>
            </BUILDING>
            <BUILDINGFLOOD>
                <COVERSTATUS Status="NEW" StartDate="20210729"></COVERSTATUS>
                <PAYABLES>
                    <SPLIT Premium="0.00"></SPLIT>
                    <RATINGINFORMATION RatingMethod="Auto" CommissionRate1="0.00000" CommissionRate2="0.00000" ExemptStampDuty="Y" PMSLink="1005070010" PriorTermBilledPremium="0.00" PriorTermAnnualPremium="0.00" PriorTermSumInsured="1"></RATINGINFORMATION>
                </PAYABLES>
                <ADJUSTMENT AdjustmentRetention="Permanent" AdjustmentType="Percent" AdjustmentValue="20.00000" AdjustmentReason="OWNER AND TENANT ON SAME TITLE"></ADJUSTMENT>
            </BUILDINGFLOOD>
        </HOUSEHOLD>
        <HOUSEHOLD RiskID="02" CoverType="AccidentalDamage" VoluntaryExcess="600" ImposedExcess="0" WallsConstruction="BrickVeneer" Size="0" BuildingType="House" BuildingLevel="Unknown" Occupied="Family" YearOfConstruction=" " Deadlocks="Y" Alarm="NoAlarm">
            <RISKADDRESS AddressId="051208029" GeoReliability="2" AddressLine1="1500 ALISON ST" Suburb="MOUNT HELENA" Postcode="006082" State="WA"></RISKADDRESS>
            <CONTENTS>
                <OTHERCONTENTS SumInsured="243900">
                    <COVERSTATUS Status="NEW" StartDate="20210729"></COVERSTATUS>
                    <PAYABLES>
                        <SPLIT Premium="1193.50"></SPLIT>
                        <RATINGINFORMATION RatingMethod="Auto" CommissionRate1="0.00000" CommissionRate2="0.00000" ExemptStampDuty="Y" PMSLink="1014430010"></RATINGINFORMATION>
                    </PAYABLES>
                </OTHERCONTENTS>
                <SPECIFIEDCONTENTS SumInsured="8000">
                    <COVERSTATUS Status="NEW" StartDate="20210729"></COVERSTATUS>
                    <PAYABLES>
                        <SPLIT Premium="45.42"></SPLIT>
                        <RATINGINFORMATION RatingMethod="Auto" CommissionRate1="0.00000" CommissionRate2="0.00000" ExemptStampDuty="Y" PMSLink="1014440010"></RATINGINFORMATION>
                    </PAYABLES>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="MINITURES" SumInsured="5000"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                    <SPECIFIEDITEM Description="ART WORK - PICTURES/POTTERY" SumInsured="3000"></SPECIFIEDITEM>
                </SPECIFIEDCONTENTS>
            </CONTENTS>
            <CONTENTSFLOOD>
                <COVERSTATUS Status="NEW" StartDate="20210729"></COVERSTATUS>
                <PAYABLES>
                    <SPLIT Premium="0.00"></SPLIT>
                    <RATINGINFORMATION RatingMethod="Auto" CommissionRate1="0.00000" CommissionRate2="0.00000" ExemptStampDuty="Y" PMSLink="1015080010"></RATINGINFORMATION>
                </PAYABLES>
            </CONTENTSFLOOD>
        </HOUSEHOLD>
    </MEMBERSAFE>
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

I believe 1st HOUSEHOLD tag shouldn't have given any value for SPECIFIEDITEM?

Comment: Can you add the exact expected result?

Comment: I also do not the `POLICY` tag in the xml file. Where should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNNEST(...) WITH ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT 
  (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyNumber', payload::xml))[1]::text AS policynumber,
  (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyType', payload::xml))[1]::text AS PolicyType,
  hh_id AS HOUSEHOLD_sequence_id,
  it_id AS SPECIFIEDITEM_sequence_id,
  (xpath('/SPECIFIEDITEM/@Description', it))[1] AS SPECIFIEDITEM_Description,
  (xpath('/SPECIFIEDITEM/@SumInsured', it))[1] AS SPECIFIEDITEM_SumInsured
FROM pms_source_xml_risks,
  unnest(xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM', payload::xml)) WITH ORDINALITY AS item (it,it_id),
  unnest(xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD', payload::xml)) WITH ORDINALITY AS household (hh,hh_id)
WHERE (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyNumber', payload::xml))[1]::text = '06C1551076'
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=279df7d0d45735b5039ed3774ba3a962)

Query using `LATERAL` adapted for two `<HOUSEHOLD>` in a single `<MEMBERSAFE>`:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyNumber', payload::xml))[1]::text AS policynumber,
    (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyType', payload::xml))[1]::text AS PolicyType,
    (xpath('HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM/@SumInsured', household_xml))[1]::text AS specifieditem_suminsured,
    household.*
  FROM pms_source_xml_risks,
  LATERAL UNNEST(xpath('/POLICY/MEMBERSAFE/HOUSEHOLD', payload::xml)) 
          WITH ORDINALITY AS household (household_xml,household_seq)
  WHERE (xpath('/POLICY/@PolicyNumber', payload::xml))[1]::text = '06C1551076' 
)
SELECT 
  j.policynumber,j.policytype,j.household_seq,
  item.specifieditem_description::text,item.specifieditem_seq,
  j.specifieditem_suminsured
FROM j,
 UNNEST(xpath('HOUSEHOLD/CONTENTS/SPECIFIEDCONTENTS/SPECIFIEDITEM/@Description', j.household_xml)) 
 WITH ORDINALITY AS item (specifieditem_description,specifieditem_seq);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a9b318a056ea5300ca71fee09c09e38)

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question with another XML data which gives strange result.

Comment: @hlagvankar with this xml it becomes a totally different query. It doesn't even have the `<POLICY>` tag.  A lateral join might be what you're looking for, but I'd need to see the expected results.

Comment: POLICY tag is same level as previous example, I just didn't add that. Let me try this one.